# Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple

Tags: python

### Below is my code for two modules. I'm trying to work with sending emails using classes.

TEMPLATE.PY

```
import os

FILE_PATH=os.path.abspath(__file__)
BASE_DIR=os.path.dirname(FILE_PATH)
TEMPLATE_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')

class Template:
    template_name=""
    context=None

    def __init__(self,template_name,context,*args,**kwargs):
        self.template_name=template_name
        self.context=context

    def get_template(self):
        template_path=os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR,self.template_name)
        if not os.path.exists(template_path):
            raise Exception('Path is non-existent!')
        template_string=''
        with open(template_path,'r') as f:
            template_string=f.read()
        return template_string

    def render(self,context=None):
        render_ctx=context
        if(self.context!=None):
            render_ctx=self.context
        if(not isinstance(render_ctx,dict)):
            render_ctx={}
        template_string=self.get_template()
        return template_string.format(**render_ctx)
```

---

SEND_MAIL.PY

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from templates import Template

username='abc@gmail.com'
password=''

class Emailer():
    subject=''
    context={}
    to_emails=[]
    has_html=False
    test_send=False
    from_email='Some email <ashuradirty@gmaill.com'
    template_html=None
    template_name=None

    def __init__(self,subject='',
                 context={},
                 to_emails=[],
                 test_send=True,
                 template_html=None,
                 template_name=None):
        self.subject=subject
        self.context=context
        assert(isinstance(to_emails,list))
        self.to_emails=to_emails
        self.test_send=test_send
        if template_name==None and template_html==None:
            raise Exception('Template required!')
        if(template_html!=None):
            self.template_html=template_html
            self.has_html=True
        self.template_name=template_name

    def format_msg(self):
        msg=MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['From']=self.from_email
        msg['To']=','.join(self.to_emails)
        msg['Subject']=self.subject

        if(self.template_name!=None):
            tmpl_string=Template(template_name=self.template_name,context=self.context)
            txt_part=MIMEText(tmpl_string.render(),'plain')
            print(txt_part)
            msg.attach(txt_part)
        if(self.template_html!=None):
            tmpl_string=Template(template_name=self.template_name,context=self.context)
            html_part=MIMEText(tmpl_string.render(),'html')
            print(html_part)
            msg.attach(html_part)
        msg_str=msg.as_string()
        return msg_str

    def send(self):
        msg=self.format_msg()
        did_send=False

        if not self.test_send:
            with smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com',port=587) as server:
                server.ehlo()
                server.starttls()
                server.login(username,password)
                try:
                    server.sendmail(from_email,to_emails,msg)
                    did_send=True
                except:
                    did_send=False
        return did_send

emlr=Emailer(subject='something',
             context={'name':'somename'},
             to_emails=['abc@gmail.com'],
             template_name='hello.txt')
print(emlr.send())
```

---

### Below is the error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 "/Users/**********/Desktop/Back2Python/Day 11/send_mail.py"
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/**********/Desktop/Back2Python/Day 11/send_mail.py", line 76, in 
> print(emlr.send())
> File "/Users/**********/Desktop/Back2Python/Day 11/send_mail.py", line 57, in send
> msg=self.format_msg()
> File "/Users/**********/Desktop/Back2Python/Day 11/send_mail.py", line 45, in format_msg
> txt_part=MIMEText(tmpl_string.render(),'plain')
> File "/Users/**********/Desktop/Back2Python/Day 11/templates.py", line 31, in render
> return template_string.format(**render_ctx)
> IndexError: Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple

Process finished with exit code 1

---

The argument 'context' in the constructor isn't unpacking with the format method of the 'template' module. What am I doing wrong? I learning Python and this is my day 11. Sorry if I've made a clumsy mistake.

Comment: Can you show us the total error? (Please Edit this in your post.)

Comment: @SharimIqbal Sorry about that. Edited just now.

Comment: The error might be with the template string. Does the template actually contain named placeholders, like `{name}`, or positional placeholders, like `{}`?

Comment: @tobias_k I found the problem. The placeholder was missing in the hello.txt file and it was in the constructor as an argument. Added the placeholder and the code now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your template string is incorrect and is not using named placeholders which is required if you are are unpacking like so `.format(**params)`

```
>>> '{name}'.format(**{'name': 'Foo'})
'Foo'
```

As the following will error

```
>>> '{}'.format(**{'name': 'Foo'})
IndexError: Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple
>>> '{0}'.format(**{'name': 'Foo'})
IndexError: Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple
```

Also note that if you have named placeholders but are missing the values for them it will also error

```
>>> '{a} {b}'.format(**{'b': 'Foo'})
KeyError: 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder was missing in the hello.txt file which was in the constructor as an argument. Added the placeholder to the hello.txt file and the code now works.

Answer (score 0):

For example if the brackets need to be left as is and one variable need to change

```
test_str = "Str with necessary brackets {} and {var} and again necessary brackets {}"
```

If you apply

```
test_str.format(var="my_var")
```

You can expect

```
"Some string with the necessary brackets {} and my_var and again necessary brackets {}"
```

but will get IndexError: Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple.

To avoid this you can try change string with {{}}

```
test_str = "Str with necessary brackets {{}} and {var} and again necessary brackets {{}}" 

test_str.format(var="my_var")
```